# While loops and step

Tags: java, loops

```
init; 
while (test) {
  statements;
  step;
    }
```

I had a question about the location of the step in the above while loop. Does it matter where the step is written? In other words does it change the any of the values in the while loop if the step is written as the first statement or somewhere in the middle or at the end? If it does can you provide a short example to illustrate that effect.

Comment: If you use the value of `step` in the loop, yes, it definitely matters. Why not use a `for loop`?

Comment: @A--C I'm trying to solve a problem using the while loop and not the for loop. I know they're interchangeable but its just an exercise.

Comment: By convention, if nothing unusual is needed, you should _generally_ put the step at the end.  At least I think that's where most people would look for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The placement of the step could definitely influence the body of the loop.  Imagine if the code below were accessing an array, the first example could miss the first element in an array.

**This outputs 0-9**

```
int x = 0;

while(x < 10){
  System.out.println(x);
  x++; 
}
```

**This outputs 1-10**

```
int x = 0;

while(x < 10){
  x++; 
  System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: @JessicM glad I could help.  This really depends on what you need to do in a loop the scenarios are endless.

Answer (score 0):

The step is just another variable.  If the statements inside your loop reference it, then yes, it matters.  If not, it's position does not matter (as long as it's somewhere in the loop).